# mapStruct: map list to other list?

Tags: mapstruct

I have a list `List<Payment>` which I'd like to map to another list `List<PaymentPlan>`. These types look like this:

```
public class Payment {

    @XmlElement(name = "Installment")
    @JsonProperty("Installment")
    private List<Installment> installments = new ArrayList<>();

    @XmlElement(name = "OriginalAmount")
    @JsonProperty("OriginalAmount")
    private BigDecimal originalAmount;

//getters setters, more attributes
}
```

and....

```
public class PaymentPlan {
    //(Installment in different package)
    private List<Installment> installments;

    @XmlElement(name = "OriginalAmount")
    @JsonProperty("OriginalAmount")
    private BigDecimal originalAmount;

//getters setters, more attributes
}
```

I expect that something like this is working...

```
@Mappings({
    @Mapping(//other mappings...),
    @Mapping(source = "payments", target = "paymentInformation.paymentPlans")
})
ResultResponse originalResponseToResultResponse(OrigResponse originalResponse);
```

...but I get:

```
Can't map property java.util.List<Payment> to java.util.List<PaymentPlan>.
Consider to declare/implement a mapping method java.util.List<PaymentPlan> map(java.util.List<Payment> value);
```

I don't know how to apply this information. First I though I need to declare some extra mapping (in the same mapper class) for the lists, so MapStruct knows how to map each field of the List types like this:

```
@Mappings({
  @Mapping(source = "payment.originalAmount", target = "paymentInformation.paymentPlan.originalAmount")
})
List<PaymentPlan> paymentToPaymentPlan(List<Payment> payment);
```

...but I get error messages like

```
The type of parameter "payment" has no property named "originalAmount".
```

Obviously I do something completely wrong, since it sound like it does not even recognize the types of the List.

How can I basically map from one List to another similar List? Obviously I somehow need to combine different mapping strategies.

btw: I know how to do it with expression mapping, like...

`@Mapping(target = "paymentPlans",expression="java(Helper.mapManually(payments))")`

but I guess MapStruct can handle this by iself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I presume you are using version `1.1.0.Final`. Your extra mapping is correct, the only difference is that you need to define a mapping without the lists MapStruct will then use that to do the mapping (the example message is a bit misleading for collections).

```
PaymentPlan paymentToPaymentPlan(Payment payment);
```

You don't even need the `@Mappings` as they would be automatically mapped. You might also need to define methods for the `Instalment` (as they are in different packages).

If you switch to 1.2.0.CR2 then MapStruct can automatically generate the methods for you.

Comment: I read this and didn't understand your answer the first time.  I didn't understand you meant to add the nonlist mapping *in addition to* the list mapping.  You might consider adding an example of the complete @Mapper file here for clarity.